# SQL agrupando informações

Tags: mysql, sql, firebird

Tenho a seguinte instrução sql:

```
SELECT * FROM TB_CADPRECO
WHERE MAT_GESTOR = 123
AND UF_PRODUTO LIKE 'PR'
AND TIPO_CAMPANHA = 5
AND DT_CAMPANHA = '01.08.2018'
UNION
SELECT * FROM TB_CADPRECO
WHERE MAT_GESTOR = 123
AND UF_PRODUTO LIKE 'PR' 
AND TIPO_CAMPANHA = 0
AND DT_CAMPANHA IS NULL
ORDER BY 1
```

Nesse cenário:

```
|produto|mat_gestor|uf_produto|tipo_campanha|dt_campanha|  dt_alteracao   |
|  1    |   123    | PR       |   0         |    null   |01.01.18 23:54:56|
|  2    |   123    | PR       |   0         |    null   |01.01.18 23:53:56|
|  3    |   123    | PR       |   0         |    null   |01.01.18 23:52:56|
|  4    |   123    | PR       |   0         |    null   |01.01.18 23:51:56|
|  5    |   123    | PR       |   0         |    null   |01.01.18 23:50:56|
|  5    |   123    | PR       |   5         | 01.08.2018|01.01.18 22:58:56|
|  2    |   123    | PR       |   5         | 01.08.2018|01.01.18 23:55:56|
```

quero que me retorne assim:

```
|produto|mat_gestor|uf_produto|tipo_campanha|dt_campanha| dt_alteracao  |
|  1    |   123    | PR       |   0         |    null   |01.01.18 23:54:56|
|  2    |   123    | PR       |   5         | 01.08.2018|01.01.18 23:55:56|
|  3    |   123    | PR       |   0         |    null   |01.01.18 23:52:56|
|  4    |   123    | PR       |   0         |    null   |01.01.18 23:51:56|
|  5    |   123    | PR       |   5         | 01.08.2018|01.01.18 22:58:56|
```

Estou tentando usar o UNION mas não deu certo.

Tentei fazer utilizando case:

```
 SELECT * FROM TB_CADPRECO CAD
 WHERE CAD.MAT_GESTOR = 2111531
 AND CAD.UF_PRODUTO LIKE 'PR' AND
 case when CAD.TIPO_CAMPANHA = 5 and CAD.DT_CAMPANHA = '01.08.2018' then
   CAD.TIPO_CAMPANHA = 5 and CAD.DT_CAMPANHA = '01.08.2018'
 else
   CAD.TIPO_CAMPANHA = 0 and CAD.DT_CAMPANHA is null
 end
 ORDER BY produto
```

Mas continua trazendo os registros duplicados.
Não consigo colocar Distinct no select, pois tenho campos de datetime.

Resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
 SELECT CAD.*, P.DESC_PRODUTO AS desc_produto,
 FROM TB_CADPRECO CAD
 LEFT JOIN TB_PRODUTO P ON CAD.COD_PRODUTO = P.COD_PRODUTO
 WHERE
 MAT_GESTOR = 123
 AND UF_PRODUTO LIKE 'PR'
 AND
 (
 (
 (TIPO_CAMPANHA = 0 AND DT_CAMPANHA IS NULL) and CAD.cod_produto not in
 (
   SELECT cod_produto FROM TB_CADPRECO
   WHERE
   MAT_GESTOR = 123
   AND UF_PRODUTO LIKE 'PR'
   AND (TIPO_CAMPANHA = 5 AND DT_CAMPANHA = '01.08.2018')
  )
 )
OR
(TIPO_CAMPANHA = 5 AND DT_CAMPANHA = '01.08.2018')
)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Não seria, pois a instrução "IN" vai trazer todos.

Answer (score 0):

Teste o seguinte código:

```
SELECT produto,mat_gestor,uf_produto,max(tipo_campanha),max(dt_campanha)
FROM TB_CADPRECO
WHERE MAT_GESTOR = 123
AND UF_PRODUTO LIKE 'PR'
AND
(
  (TIPO_CAMPANHA = 5 AND DT_CAMPANHA = '01.08.2018')
  OR
  (TIPO_CAMPANHA = 0 AND DT_CAMPANHA IS NULL)
)
GROUP BY produto,mat_gestor,uf_produto
ORDER BY produto
```

Comment: Felipe, existe outra forma de usar o "SELECT * " pois tenho vários campos, na ilustração de exemplo passei somente alguns.

Comment: @TiagoCasanova como nesta solução eu agrupei os dados, terá que descrever todos eles no select e também no group by, porém no group by não devem estar os campos com função de agregação, que no caso são: tipo_campanha,dt_campanha

Comment: Não consigo pois tenho campo datetime, que trago no select *, caso trazer no select manual, o filtro não funciona, pois continua trazendo os dois registro.

Comment: Não entendi o seu problema com o campo DateTime... não tem problema algum ter um campo DateTime e também o select * não tem nenhuma alteração na execução real do script. Utilizar o * ou descrever todos os campos acaba sendo o mesmo comando executado.

Comment: Me desculpe não fui muito claro, eu tenho um campo, por exemplo, PC_INDICE  que num registro esta null  no outro esta com valor, quando coloco esse campo no select ele traz os dois registro, tipo ele "ignora" o max.

Comment: Colocou MAX(PC_INDICE) e **não** colocou ele no group by? Consegue editar a pergunta e incluir o select completo, mesmo que seja grande?

Comment: Consegue de outro jeito, mas valeu pelas dicas.

Comment: Boa! Compartilhe como resolveu, para que o pessoal que chegar ao tópico, encontrar a solução.